# How to find and copy a link from "font.googleapis"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Where can i find the full link of "http://https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400". I need to include it on a HTML doc.
I have tried googling it but the page cannot be found or is it an old api link?

Comment: what do you mean by full link?

Answer (score 0):

You can select as many fonts as you want from [fonts.google.com](http://fonts.google.com) and it will give you a link with all the parameters already in it :)
[Here's Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)

Answer (score 0):

You Can visit [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)

Search For your required font and select the required style
[image: Google Fonts]

For Example You selected roboto Medium
[image]

Then copy the css code and paste it on top of the file.
and add font-family attribute in the tag.

for example:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap');

body{
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```